# Inserting UUID manually into Oracle 11g Database?

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, jpa

I am using oracle 11g with Hibernate JPA technology. I am able to run the code successfully for generating the UUID in JPA using annotations. Here is my entity..

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator = "UUID")
@GenericGenerator(name = "UUID", strategy = "org.hibernate.id.UUIDGenerator")
@Column(name = "id", updatable = false, nullable = false)
private UUID Id;

public UUID getId() {
    return Id;
}
```

**NOTE:** The UUID Datatype in entity is java.util.UUID package.

Here is my problem: I have certain queries where I have a relationship with parent and child table which need to be inserted manually (seek data). So I wanted to generate UUIDs from within java and to insert them into the database so that my parent child table relation won't break.

Creating a company with name XYZ and assigning to ABC user (can't do with application since this need to be preloaded)

How do I insert a UUID manually in oracle SQL queries? I came across sys_GUID(), but can't use this because it will be different each time we run.

Here is my table and SQL Query.

```
id  --- > raw(255)
employee_name ---> varchar2(255)

INSERT INTO XYZ(id,employee_name)
VALUES('5c7c417e-7c62-4d61-a379-dd7ca434f15d','OjE');
```

***NOTE : 5c7c417e-7c62-4d61-a379-dd7ca434f15d is java util UUID***

> Error report - SQL Error: ORA-01465: invalid hex number
>   01465. 00000 -  "invalid hex number"
>   *Cause:
>   *Action:

Comment: Why can't you preload User?

Comment: @Rohit I am preloading the user with sql queries! I hope this is wt ur telling

Comment: If I understand correctly you want to preload the DB with User and Company outside the application whilst generating the UUID and setting the correct reference from user to company?

Comment: @Rohit yes buddy

Comment: - is not hex value. you could use utl_raw.cast_to_raw('..')